# WSO2 ESB - Storing/Logging Messages in db

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

We have decided to try WSO2 ESB and for our project we need to save all messages in a database to be viewable through a web based custom interface.

What's the best way to store all the complete requests and responses in a database? Is there any mediator for this purpose? We looked into STORE and DBREPORT and apparently none are built for this purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use DBReport to do so - a simple SQL insert and as parameter you select the whole MessageContext.
See this link and just select the value you want to save:

[DBReport Documentation](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/mediators/dbreport.html)

Other solution is to create your own Custom Mediator(Class Mediator) and do your insert directly within normal Java code. Creating a Class Mediator just write a new Java Class and implement the org.apache.synapse.Mediator class. Build a .jar and copy it to the component/lib directory in your WSO2 installation folder.

[Class Mediator](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/mediators/class.html)

Comment: Nice. DBReport worked perfectly and I'm saving all required message properties into DB - including message header and body. Is there any property for message direction in Synapse (or axis2 etc) scope? I need to find out if the message is a request or a response. Thanks.